# How to check if spark dataframe is empty?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Right now, I have to use `df.count > 0` to check if the `DataFrame` is empty or not. But it is kind of inefficient. Is there any better way to do that?

PS: I want to check if it's empty so that I only save the `DataFrame` if it's not empty

Answer (score 217):

For Spark 2.1.0, my suggestion would be to use `head(n: Int)` or `take(n: Int)` with `isEmpty`, whichever one has the clearest intent to you.

```scala
df.head(1).isEmpty
df.take(1).isEmpty
```

with Python equivalent:

```py
len(df.head(1)) == 0  # or bool(df.head(1))
len(df.take(1)) == 0  # or bool(df.take(1))
```

Using `df.first()` and `df.head()` will both return the `java.util.NoSuchElementException` if the DataFrame is empty. `first()` calls `head()` directly, which calls `head(1).head`.

```scala
def first(): T = head()
def head(): T = head(1).head
```

`head(1)` returns an Array, so taking `head` on that Array causes the `java.util.NoSuchElementException` when the DataFrame is empty.

```scala
def head(n: Int): Array[T] = withAction("head", limit(n).queryExecution)(collectFromPlan)
```

So instead of calling `head()`, use `head(1)` directly to get the array and then you can use `isEmpty`.

`take(n)` is also equivalent to `head(n)`...

```scala
def take(n: Int): Array[T] = head(n)
```

And `limit(1).collect()` is equivalent to `head(1)` (notice `limit(n).queryExecution` in the `head(n: Int)` method), so the following are all equivalent, at least from what I can tell, and you won't have to catch a `java.util.NoSuchElementException` exception when the DataFrame is empty.

```scala
df.head(1).isEmpty
df.take(1).isEmpty
df.limit(1).collect().isEmpty
```

I know this is an older question so hopefully it will help someone using a newer version of Spark.

Comment: For those using pyspark. isEmpty is not a thing. Do len(d.head(1)) > 0 instead.

Comment: why is this better then `df.rdd.isEmpty`?

Comment: df.head(1).isEmpty is taking huge time is there any other optimized solution for this.

Comment: Hey @Rakesh Sabbani, If `df.head(1)` is taking a large amount of time, it's *probably* because your `df`'s execution plan is doing something complicated that prevents spark from taking shortcuts. For example, if you are just reading from parquet files, `df = spark.read.parquet(...)`, I'm pretty sure spark will only read one file partition. But if your `df` is doing other things like aggregations, you may be inadvertently forcing spark to read and process a large portion, if not all, of you source data.

Comment: just reporting my experience to AVOID: I was using `df.limit(1).count()` naively. On big datasets it takes much more time than the reported examples by @hulin003 which are almost instantaneous

Comment: a little remark to this solution: you should avoid using df.head(1).isEmpty OR
df.take(1).isEmpty on dataframes with > 100 columns because in can cause org.codehaus.janino.JaninoRuntimeException

Comment: @hulin003 I'm using df.take(1).isEmpty based on your answer, but it takes a very long time(2 mins) for even a a couple of hundred rows. Any help?

Comment: For pyspark, simply use `if df.head(1): ...`. Head returns a list, which might be empty, and empty lists evaluate to `False`. That's the idiomatic way in python.

Answer (score 63):

I would say to just grab the underlying `RDD`. In Scala:

```scala
df.rdd.isEmpty
```

in Python:

```python
df.rdd.isEmpty()
```

That being said, all this does is call `take(1).length`, so it'll do the same thing as Rohan answered...just maybe slightly more explicit?

Comment: This is surprisingly slower than df.count() == 0 in my case

Comment: Isn't converting to rdd a heavy task?

Comment: Not really. RDD's still are the underpinning of everything Spark for the most part.

Comment: Don't convert the df to RDD. It slows down the process. If you convert it will convert whole DF to RDD and check if its empty. Think if DF has millions of rows, it takes lot of time in converting to RDD itself.

Comment: .rdd slows down so much the process like a lot

Comment: If you call rdd's `isEmpty` method on a big dataframe, it will extremely slow it down especially when the dataframe isn't cached.

Answer (score 38):

I had the same question, and I tested 3 main solution :

1. `(df != null) && (df.count > 0)`
2. `df.head(1).isEmpty()` as @hulin003 suggest
3. `df.rdd.isEmpty()` as @Justin Pihony suggest

and of course the 3 works, however in term of perfermance, here is what I found, when executing the these methods on the same DF in my machine, in terme of execution time :

1. it takes ~9366ms
2. it takes ~5607ms
3. it takes ~1921ms

therefore I think that the best solution is **`df.rdd.isEmpty()` as @Justin Pihony suggest**

Comment: out of curiosity... what size DataFrames was this tested with?

Comment: I've tested 10 million rows... and got the same time as for df.count() or df.rdd.isEmpty()

Comment: In my use case, I want to test if at least one row contains a particular string. `isEmpy()` is faster the majority of times since it finds at least a row and stops. When checking for a string not found in the df. Both `count()` and `isEmpty()` have to scan the whole df and then take the same time.

Answer (score 21):

Since Spark 2.4.0 there is [`Dataset.isEmpty`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#isEmpty--).

It's [implementation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala) is :

```scala
def isEmpty: Boolean = 
  withAction("isEmpty", limit(1).groupBy().count().queryExecution) { plan =>
    plan.executeCollect().head.getLong(0) == 0
}
```

Note that a `DataFrame` is no longer a class in Scala, it's just a [type alias](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/package.scala) (probably changed with Spark 2.0):

```scala
type DataFrame = Dataset[Row]
```

Comment: isEmpty is slower than df.head(1).isEmpty

Comment: @Sandeep540 Really? Benchmark? Your proposal instantiates at least one row. The Spark implementation just transports a number. head() is using limit() as well, the groupBy() is not really doing anything, it is required to get a RelationalGroupedDataset which in turn provides count(). So that should not be significantly slower. It is probably faster in case of a data set which contains a lot of columns (possibly denormalized nested data). Anway you have to type less :-)

Comment: Beware: I am using `.option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")` and `df.isEmpty` returned `false` whereas `df.head(1).isEmpty` returned the correct result of `true` because... all of the rows were malformed (someone upstream changed the schema on me).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now with a built-in method.

Answer (score 16):

You can take advantage of the `head()` (or `first()`) functions to see if the `DataFrame` has a single row. If so, it is not empty.

Comment: if dataframe is empty it throws "java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator"  ; [Spark 1.3.1]

Answer (score 14):

**PySpark 3.3.0+ / Scala 2.4.0+**

```
df.isEmpty()
```

Comment: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'isEmpty'. Spark 3.0

Comment: In PySpark, it's introduced only from version 3.3.0

Comment: In scala current you should do df.isEmpty without parenthesis ().

Answer (score 11):

If you do `df.count > 0`. It takes the counts of all partitions across all executors and add them up at Driver. This take a while when you are dealing with millions of rows.

The best way to do this is to perform `df.take(1)` and check if its null. This will return `java.util.NoSuchElementException` so better to put a try around `df.take(1)`.

The dataframe return an error when `take(1)` is done instead of an empty row. I have highlighted the specific code lines where it throws the error.

[image]

Comment: if you run this on a massive dataframe with millions of records that `count` method is going to take some time.

Comment: using df.take(1) when the df is empty results in getting back an empty ROW which cannot be compared with null

Comment: i'm using first() instead of take(1) in a try/catch block and it works

Comment: @LetsPlayYahtzee I have updated the answer with same run and picture that shows error. take(1) returns Array[Row]. And when Array doesn't have any values, by default it gives ArrayOutOfBounds. So I don't think it gives an empty Row. I would say to observe this and change the vote.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Pyspark, you could also do:

```
len(df.head(1)) > 0
```

Answer (score 6):

For Java users you can use this on a dataset :

```
public boolean isDatasetEmpty(Dataset<Row> ds) {
        boolean isEmpty;
        try {
            isEmpty = ((Row[]) ds.head(1)).length == 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return true;
        }
        return isEmpty;
}
```

This check all possible scenarios ( empty, null ).

Answer (score 4):

In Scala you can use implicits to **add** the methods `isEmpty()` and `nonEmpty()` to the DataFrame API, which will make the code a bit nicer to read.

```scala
object DataFrameExtensions {
  implicit def extendedDataFrame(dataFrame: DataFrame): ExtendedDataFrame = 
    new ExtendedDataFrame(dataFrame: DataFrame)

  class ExtendedDataFrame(dataFrame: DataFrame) {
    def isEmpty(): Boolean = dataFrame.head(1).isEmpty // Any implementation can be used
    def nonEmpty(): Boolean = !isEmpty
  }
}
```

Here, other methods can be added as well. To use the implicit conversion, use `import DataFrameExtensions._` in the file you want to use the extended functionality. Afterwards, the methods can be used directly as so:

```scala
val df: DataFrame = ...
if (df.isEmpty) {
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

On PySpark, you can also use this `bool(df.head(1))` to obtain a `True` of `False` value

It returns `False` if the dataframe contains no rows

Answer (score 1):

If you want only to find out whether the `DataFrame` is empty, then `df.isEmpty`, `df.head(1).isEmpty()` or `df.rdd.isEmpty()` should work, these are taking a `limit(1)` if you `examine` them:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[count(1)], output=[count#52L])
+- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_count(1)], output=[count#60L])
   +- *(2) GlobalLimit 1
      +- Exchange SinglePartition
         +- *(1) LocalLimit 1
            ... // the rest of the plan related to your computation
```

But if you are doing some other computation that requires a lot of memory and you don't want to cache your `DataFrame` just to check whether it is empty, then you can use an accumulator:

```scala
def accumulateRows(acc: LongAccumulator)(df: DataFrame): DataFrame =
  df.map { row => // we map to the same row, count during this map
    acc.add(1)
    row
  }(RowEncoder(df.schema))

val rowAccumulator = spark.sparkContext.longAccumulator("Row Accumulator")
val countedDF = df.transform(accumulateRows(rowAccumulator))
countedDF.write.saveAsTable(...) // main action
val isEmpty = rowAccumulator.isZero
```

Note that to see the row count, you should first perform the action. If we change the order of the last 2 lines, `isEmpty` will be `true` regardless of the computation.

Answer (score 0):

I found that on some cases:

```
>>>print(type(df))
<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>

>>>df.take(1).isEmpty
'list' object has no attribute 'isEmpty'
```

this is same for "length" or replace take() by head()

[Solution] for the issue we can use.

```
>>>df.limit(2).count() > 1
False
```

Answer (score 0):

My case was a bit different and I want to share it with you all.
My Dataframe was delivered empty however, there was a null value record. The dataframe is considered empty but it wasn't actually. Therefore I wrote the below code as a solution for my problem.

My Problem:
When I issue `df.count()` I don't get `0` but one record with null values. If I issue `df.rdd.isEmpty()` I get `False`.

The Solution:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,when
def isDfEmpty(df):
  if df.count() == 1: #When df has only one record
    _df_ = df.select([when(col(c)=="",None).otherwise(col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).na.drop('all')
    return(_df_.rdd.isEmpty())
  else:
    return False

isDfEmpty(df) #Replace df with your respective dataframe variable
```

Note: In my case I got only one record in the empty dataframe. If that is not the case please reconsider the `if` condition.

Comment: Unclear how this answers the actual question, then. Null values and empty strings aren't technically empty dataframes. Have you tried `dropNa` operation before counting?

Answer (score -1):

```
df1.take(1).length>0
```

The `take` method returns the array of rows, so if the array size is equal to zero, there are no records in `df`.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it like:

```
val df = sqlContext.emptyDataFrame
if( df.eq(sqlContext.emptyDataFrame) )
    println("empty df ")
else 
    println("normal df")
```

Comment: won't it require the `schema` of two dataframes (`sqlContext.emptyDataFrame` & `df`) to be same in order to ever return `true`?

Comment: This won't work. `eq` is inherited from `AnyRef` and _tests whether the argument (that) is a reference to the receiver object (this)._

Answer (score -2):

`dataframe.limit(1).count > 0`

This also triggers a job but since we are selecting single record, even in case of billion scale records the time consumption could be much lower.

From:
https://medium.com/checking-emptiness-in-distributed-objects/count-vs-isempty-surprised-to-see-the-impact-fa70c0246ee0

Comment: All these are bad options taking almost equal time

Comment: @PushpendraJaiswal yes, and in a world of bad options, we should chose the best bad option

Answer (score -2):

Let's suppose we have the following empty dataframe:

```
df = spark.sql("show tables").limit(0)
```

If you are using Spark 2.1, for pyspark, to check if this dataframe is empty, you can use:

```
df.count() > 0
```

Or

```
bool(df.head(1))
```