# Fastest way to check if DataFrame(Scala) is empty?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to check if DataFrame(**Scala**) is empty in fastest way?I use **DF.limit(1).rdd.isEmpty**, faster than DF.rdd.isEmpty,but not ideal.Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if spark dataframe is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707620/how-to-check-if-spark-dataframe-is-empty)

Answer (score 3):

I usually wrap a call to `first` around a `Try`:

```
import scala.util.Try

val t = Try(df.first)
```

From there you can match on it if it's a `Success` or `Failure` to control logic:

```
import scala.util.{Success,Failure}

t match {
  case Success(df) => //do stuff with the dataframe

  case Failure(e) => 
    // dataframe is empty; do other stuff
    //e.getMessage will return the exception message
}
```

Comment: I previously used df.first,but I find it's slower than limit(1)?why?

Comment: oh,I'm sorry,I test df.first.if it's empty,it occurs this error---java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator

Comment: Oops, my mistake; I meant `Try` instead of `Option`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: thanks,but its performance is better than DF.limit(1).rdd.isEmpty?

Comment: Looking at the source code of `limit` and `head` it looks like `head` calls `limit(1)`, so If ever there was a difference I doubt it would be anything significant in this instance.Still, `df.head` is cleaner and easier to understand (for me, at least).