# Alternative to count in Spark sql to check if a query return empty result

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I know `count` action can be expensive in Spark, so to improve performance I'd like to have a different way just to check if a query can return any results

Here is what I did

```
var df = spark.sql("select * from table_name where condition = 'blah' limit 1");
var dfEmpty = df.head(1).isEmpty;
```

Is it a valid solution or is there any potential uncaught error if I use above solution to check query result? It is a lot faster though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if spark dataframe is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707620/how-to-check-if-spark-dataframe-is-empty)

Comment: not exactly duplicate.... user already  knew that he can do that , is that efficient or not is the question or any better alternative is there or not is the query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`isEmpty`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L613) is head of the data.. this is quite resonable to check empty or not and it was given by spark api and is optimized... Hence,  I'd prefer this...

Also in the query I think limit 1 is not required.

```
  /**
   * Returns true if the `Dataset` is empty.
   *
   * @group basic
   * @since 2.4.0
   */
  def isEmpty: Boolean = withAction("isEmpty", limit(1).groupBy().count().queryExecution) { plan =>
    plan.executeCollect().head.getLong(0) == 0
  }
```

Comment: can you help and suggest how to handle this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036791/while-writing-to-hdfs-path-getting-error-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-rename

Answer (score 3):

I think this is ok, I guess you could also omit the `limit(1)` because this is also part of the implementation of `df.isEmpty`. See also [How to check if spark dataframe is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707620/how-to-check-if-spark-dataframe-is-empty).

Note that the solution with `df.isEmpty` does may not evaluate all columns. E.g. if you have an UDF for 1 column, this will probabely not execute and could throws exceptions on a real query. `df.head(1).isEmpty` on the other hand will evaluate all columns for 1 rows.