# Dataframe empty check pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to check if a dataframe is empty in Pyspark using below.

```
print(df.head(1).isEmpty)
```

But, I am getting an error

```
Attribute error: 'list' object has no attribute 'isEmpty'.
```

I checked if my object is really a dd using type(df) and it is class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.Dataframe'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if spark dataframe is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707620/how-to-check-if-spark-dataframe-is-empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used df.first() == None to evaluate if my spark dataframe is empty

Comment: `df.first() is None` would be the preferred syntax.

Answer (score 1):

When u do a `head(1)` it returns a list.
So that’s the reason for your error.

You have to just do `df.isEmpty()`.

Comment: Now getting dataframe object has no attribute isEmpty

Comment: Df.first() == None worked for me

Answer (score 0):

`df.head(1)` returns a list corresponding to the first row of `df`.

You can check if this list is empty "[ ]" using a bool type condition as in:

```
if df.head(1):
    print("there is something")
else:
    print("df is empty")

>>> 'df is empty'
```

Empty lists are implicity "False".

For better explanation, please head over to [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to check if `df.count()==0`

Comment: This could cause unnecessary computation on Spark, especially for large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Df.isEmpty would work for everyone starting from spark version 3.3.0. Earlier spark version might not support isEmpty method for pyspark.